# Link a view to the top "create" button of Odoo in order to add an entry

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I would like to know if it is possible to link a view with the top "Create button" of a custom module given that this button isn't a part of any view.

Now when I click on this button Odoo opens a new row that I have to fill but I would like to open a view (or a wizard) in order to add this new entry.

I searched and found nothing interesting on google/odoo forum/irc... But I have been told that this process is done in JS ?

The form when we click on "Create" from the quotation page would be perfect but I can't find how it is done.

Comment: When you click on create button, it opens the form view corresponding to your model unless you set editable=bottom or top in tree view. Can you explain what do you expect exactly ?

Comment: Thanks it was silly... I removed editable=bottom and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by overriding the original create method
then at the return statement you should return the view.

in code your return would look like this (but with other paramaters):
    return {
        'name': 'Quotations',
        'view_type': 'tree',
        "view_mode": 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'sale.order',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'search_view_id': sale_order_tree,
    }